# MacBook keeps Panic (RAM problem?)

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, kernel-panic

I’m having a major problem with my MacBook Pro 15" *(Mid 2012 - non-retina)*

In 2012 I bought my MacBook in connection with my education. About 6 month after I've bought it, I got my first **Kernel Panic** and ever since it's just gotten even worse.

The Panic can happen any time no matter what I do on it like watching videos/movies, listen to music, browsing on the internet etc... But when I do heavy stuff like working in Photoshop, editing videos and such I've noticed that it happens more frequently. Some times it can happen up to 20-30 times a day.

Because of it being a computer I've bought in connection my previous study, I do not have any warranty on it anymore, and there is no Apple Stores in my country where I can bring it to.

---

At first I thought it could be a software-related problem, so this is what I've tried to fix it myself:

- Removed and/or reinstalled apps the **Kernel Panic report** told was the reason for the Panic
- Always made sure that all the apps and the system was up-to-date
- Cleaned up all my documents and files
- ..and followed a lot of different tutorials with no luck

I've also tried to start the computer in Safe Mode, and tested if the Panic would occur on another user. But also here it happened.

Then I tried to run the **Apple Hardware Test** to test if it was hardware-related.

A few seconds after I pressed the "Test button" the computer froze while testing the memory. I tried it three more times, with the same result. I then tried to remove one of two the RAM modules from the upper slot and run the test again. This time the test was completed, saying that it had detected an error:

```
Test Results
--------------------------------------------------
Alert! Apple Hardware Test has detected an error.

4MEM/61/40000000: 0x80959f90



Pass Number: 1,
Total Time Testing: 2 minutes 36 seconds
```

Now I was pretty sure that the problem cased by the RAM, but I didn't knew if it was a faulty RAM module or a faulty RAM slot.

> In my MAC I have 2x8GB Kingston DDR3 1600 MHz RAM modules

So I tried to put the RAM module in the other RAM slot and run the test again. Here it didn't detect any errors. The only thing I noticed were that the test never said that it was "complete" and the mouse and keyboard were very laggy, taking about 1-2 seconds to respond, but I don't know if thats normal or not.

The other RAM module returned the exact same results.

So now everything is pointing the the problem might be a faulty RAM slot.
But a few hours ago while using only one RAM module in the upper RAM slot I had two new panics. Now I am confused.

What is really causing the Panic problem? The RAM modules, the RAM slots or something completely different?

Any one who can help me in this?

- Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to work with _Known Good RAM_. These are RAM Modules that have been tested to be _know good_ either in a RAM Module Tester or another non-problematic system and in doing so if there are any issues then it obviously isn't the RAM since it was tested and is _Known Good RAM_. Once you have _Known Good RAM_, you test each RAM Slot independently with a Memory Test App running from a _Known Good Boot Source_, e.g. a USB Flash Drive running appropriate software. Then test with all RAM Slots full.

Comment: If any of the test fail using _Known Good RAM_ then the issue is elsewhere and since the software source is also _known good_, the issue is other hardware and will require more specific testing for the remaining hardware.